# Hamming distance between two binary strings not working

Tags: python, binary, bit, hamming-distance

I found an interesting algorithm to calculate hamming distance on [this](http://jhafranco.com/2012/02/12/hamming-distance/) site:

```
def hamming2(x,y):
    """Calculate the Hamming distance between two bit strings"""
    assert len(x) == len(y)
    count,z = 0,x^y
    while z:
        count += 1
        z &= z-1 # magic!
    return count
```

The point is that this algorithm only works on bit strings and I'm trying to compare two strings that are binary but they are in string format, like

```
'100010'
'101000'
```

How can I make them work with this algorithm?

Comment: What is the question? Is there any error?

Comment: `bin(int('100010',2))` produces binary.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Implement it:

```
def hamming2(s1, s2):
    """Calculate the Hamming distance between two bit strings"""
    assert len(s1) == len(s2)
    return sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))
```

And test it:

```
assert hamming2("1010", "1111") == 2
assert hamming2("1111", "0000") == 4
assert hamming2("1111", "1111") == 0
```

Answer (score 5):

If we are to stick with the original algorithm, we need to convert the strings to integers to be able to use the bitwise operators.

```
def hamming2(x_str, y_str):
    """Calculate the Hamming distance between two bit strings"""
    assert len(x_str) == len(y_str)
    x, y = int(x_str, 2), int(y_str, 2)  # '2' specifies we are reading a binary number
    count, z = 0, x ^ y
    while z:
        count += 1
        z &= z - 1  # magic!
    return count
```

Then we can call it as follows:

```
print(hamming2('100010', '101000'))
```

While this algorithm is cool as a novelty, having to convert to a string likely negates any speed advantage it might have. The answer @dlask posted is much more succinct.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I use to calculate the Hamming distance.
It counts the # of differences between equal length strings.

```
def hamdist(str1, str2):
    diffs = 0
    for ch1, ch2 in zip(str1, str2):
        if ch1 != ch2:
            diffs += 1
    return diffs
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this explains well `The Hamming distance` between two strings

```
def hammingDist(s1, s2):
    bytesS1=bytes(s1, encoding="ascii")
    bytesS2=bytes(s2, encoding="ascii")
    diff=0
    for i in range(min(len(bytesS1),len(bytesS2))):
        if(bytesS1[i]^bytesS2[i]!=0):
            diff+=1
    return(diff)
```